Multivariate vs Univariate models in brms: Equivalence and computational efficacy
In R's brms package, I am analyzing multiple response variables. I understand that setting set_rescor(FALSE) in a multivariate model specifies that residual correlations between response variables are not modeled. My questions are:

Will the parameter estimates from a multivariate model with set_rescor(FALSE) be equivalent to those obtained from fitting separate univariate models for each response variable?
Is the multivariate approach without modeling response correlations more computationally efficient than fitting multiple univariate models?

